# How to install a language pack into a now-defunct 3rd-party keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, languages

There's this keyboard I really love called 8pen. I made the mistake of uninstalling it without checking and then later realized that it had been pulled from the app store, and the developer seems to have ceased all activity since 2013 . . .
I have the app now (version 2.6.0.1), but it will no longer download language packs from the developer and therefore doesn't have predictive text, which was one of the app's original strong points.  Presumably it can't download the language packs because the download servers have been unplugged.

Is there some way to get into the app's file system and install a language pack by hand?  I would just want English.

Answer (score 2):

Confirmed to work on Android 5.1.1 with 8pen version 2.6.1 and 2.7

Since mid-2014, 8pen ( is only accessible from your purchases in Google Play) language packs no longer install for the keyboard since the servers are no longer operating. Luckily, one of my roomates hasn't updated his phone since he downloaded the English dictionary.

Using Android File Manager I copied the original dictionary file

`Android/data/com.eightpen.android.eightpen`

and loaded it onto my Nexus 7 which has 8pen version 2.7 installed. After clicking to "download" the language pack, it successfully read the new files and the dictionary is operational.

Unfortunately while trying to figure all this out I uninstalled by 2.7 version and can't get it back... but the same method is working on version 2.6 on my Nexus 6.

While this is not the most elegant solution, you can [download the file you need from here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0dbRvWC2o1zX2xSUnJMTmpKYkk/view?usp=sharing) and copy the folder needed into Android/data. I've included a README with detailed steps. Happy 8penning!

(Now to figure out how to get version 2.7 back.)

Comment: This is not an answer that attempts to solve.

Comment: I am back with an update! While I cannot confirm this works with version 2.7, you can get the English language pack to work on version 2.6! Using Android File Transfer I successfully copied the original language pack into Android/Data. I am new to this forum so I am unsure how to share the appropriate files for copying.

Comment: Start by editing your old answer and insert your new answer. Add a disclaimer that it works with version xx on Android version xx device xx. Hyperlink the app you used to play store and state why you choose that app. Mention all detailed steps.If required upload photos to provide clarity. Use markdown formatting (see help on the extreme right). Mention sources, preferably technical or blogs where you read this and hyperlink them. If it is your own idea outline the logic. Look around for answers from people whose reputation is 1000+, to get a good idea. Don't fret, start

Comment: 1.I don't see Android File Manager on the play store. Give the correct name and hyperlink 2. "Loaded into nexus 7". How.Mention the location where you copied the files and original files using {} for formatting (click on that icon and paste your text  3. You can consider adding README text in the answer properly formatted. Use Bold,serial where needed.+1 from me for attempting